# C# Linq Registry values to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am trying to enumerate the registry to fetch a list of installed applications and return them via Linq to a DataTable in C#.

I have tried various things including sanitizing it as XML (which worked), however it seemed rather inefficient as ultimately, i require this as DataTable object.

Here is where i am at currently:

```
            //Warning 
   public static DataRow DataRowInstalledApplication (this RegistryKey rgkey, string keyName)
        {
            RegistryKey key = rgkey.OpenSubKey(keyName, false);
            try
            {
                //Application Name is mandetory for a given key.
                if (key == null|| key.RegToString("DisplayName", false) == null )return null;
                //Build a sanitised data row
                var rowBuilder = new DataTable().NewRow();
                rowBuilder["DisplayName"] = key.RegToString("DisplayName");
                rowBuilder["UninstallString"] = key.RegToString("UninstallString");
                rowBuilder["InstallLocation"] = key.RegToString("InstallLocation");
                rowBuilder["Publisher"] = key.RegToString("Publisher");
                rowBuilder["DisplayIcon"] = key.RegToString("DisplayIcon");

                return rowBuilder;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (key != null) key.Close();
            }

        }
```

Here is the method that contains the Linq:

```
        public DataTable GetRegistryApplicationDataTable(RegistryKey registryKey, string tableName)
    {

        if (registryKey != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //change to throw non critical error
                var installedListXml = new DataTable(tableName, from name in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames()
                                                                let app = registryKey.DataRowInstalledApplication(name)

                                                                select app);
                return installedListXml;
            }
            catch
            {
                return new DataTable(tableName);
            }
            finally
            {
                registryKey.Close();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

The main problem i have is that i do not really understand Linq very well. Mainly how individual values are used during the iteration to call other things similar to

```
foreach (string value in collection)
{
    Somefunction(value);
}
```

, in the case of the registry values i am trying to retrieve, i do not understand how to make a Linq query pass each key name to function, which will generate a row and the Linq Query return as a data table.

I would be grateful of any pointers!  thanks

ps i call the above with

```
private static readonly RegistryKey HKLMUninstallKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

GetRegistryApplicationDataTable(HKLMUninstallKey, "Computer")
```

and expect back a data table called computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is your linq statement. You are trying to pass an `IEnumerable` into a constructor that is expecting either a (`string`) or a (`string`, `string`). If you modify your logic to this:

```
var query = from name in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames()
let app = registryKey.DataRowInstalledApplication(name)
select app;

foreach(var result in query)
{
    var installedListXml = new DataTable(tableName, result);
}
```

That would work IF result was actually a string, but it's a `DataRow`, which is not a valid parameter for a `DataTable` constructor. Instead, there is an extension method you can call on the resulting query to copy to a data table, like so:

```
var query = from name in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames()
let app = registryKey.DataRowInstalledApplication(name)
select app;

var installedListXml = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

When you write a LINQ query statement, it is not executed until you try to enumerate over the results. `CopyToDataTable` does this, so if you were to step through your code you will notice that your function `DataRowInstalledApplication` will not be called until you call `CopyToDataTable` and not when you first assign `query`. The result you receive is an `Enumerator` that you can treat just like any other, whether that's using in a `foreach` loop or calling `ToList` or so forth. Inside the linq query itself, you are actually iterating over other values, in this case `GetSubKeyNames`. It would be functionally equivalent if you were to do this instead:

```
var dataRows = new List<DataRow>();
foreach(var name in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    dataRows.Add(registryKey.DataRowInstalledApplication(name));
}

return dataRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and explanation, very helpful!